# In Perl pattern match, print the matched string up to the match

Tags: regex, perl

Is there a way to print just the matched string upto the match?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $match_re = qr/\QCopyright (c) \E( \d .* ) \Q by Bill Shakespeare.\E/xi;

my $str = 'Copyright (c) 2008,2009-2011 by Wordsworth';

if ($str =~ $match_re) {
   print "\ncomplete match\n";
} else {
   print "\npartial match: \n";
}
```

In this example, I want to print `partial match: Copyright (c) 2008,2009-2011 by` because it matched up to this.

Comment: So if `$str` were `Copyright (foo)` you would just want to print `Copyright (`?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, yes

Comment: Depending on version, `${^PREMATCH}`

Comment: `${^PREMATCH}` is the part of the string up to the part that matches the regexp. In this case the string just doesn't match.

Comment: @stevieb 1) That returns the text *before* the match, not the text that actually matched 2) Even if it did return the correct text, it would only work if the entire pattern matched

Comment: The concept makes no sense as defined. The regex engine usually backtracks NUMEROUS times, so there are many many many partial matches. Ignoring the fact that `Copyr` is also a partial match in your example, consider what would happen if the name was `Cory` instead of `Wordsworth`. That would mean that `Co` in `Cory` would also be a partial match. Please provide a better definition of what you want to do.

Comment: @ikegami I think they want the longest common prefix, except the prefix is a regex instead of a fixed string.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~rsavage/Regexp-Assemble-0.37/lib/Regexp/Assemble.pm

Comment: I want add a mark, like `^` where the pattern match fails, so it will be easy to identify where the mismatch is, e.g, if `$str` has `Copyright (c) 2008,2009-2011 by Bill Shaakespeare`, then I like to print `Copyright (c) 2008,2009-2011 by Bill Shaa^kespeare` so its easy to identify the typos.

Answer (score 0):

Assume a standard BibTeX processed entry (bbl) starting with

```
$string ='\bibitem{bibtex_key} rest';
```

You can extract the two parts using the following line:

```
 my ($bibtex_key, $rest) = $string =~ m/\\bibitem\{(.*)\}(.*)/;
```

Now you can easily adapt it to your needs :)